# Google maps api: force map to do not handle click inside infobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my app user create marker when he click by map. So code like this:

```
function placeMarker(map, location) {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: location,
         map: map
     //other...
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: ballon.get(0)
     });

     ballon.find("#delete-btn").click(function(){
        infowindow.close();
        $mapPreview.data("markers")[id].marker.setMap(null);
        delete $this.data("markers")[id];
     });
});
```

`"#delete-btn"` is inside `infowindow`. Problem is when user click on `"#delete-btn"` he also create new marker on map. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
baloon.find("#delete-btn").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
```

Pass the event variable through to the click function `(e)`, and then stop the event propagation using `e.stopPropagation()`

This will stop the event from bubbling up through the DOM and getting picked up by various other listeners, like those on the map.

Comment: Will that also work in IE? I used to do different things, one for real browsers and another for IE, such as: function(ev) {
  try{ev.stopPropagation()}catch(e){event.cancelBubble=true};

Comment: @Marcelo - yes it will work in IE. You're actually getting a jQuery event, not a browser event, and jQuery normalises `e.preventDefault()` / `e.stopPropagation()`